# Библиотека для функции size

Tags: библиотеки, c++, функции

Есть массив 
`string concatpaths[k]`.
Какой h-файл надо подключить, чтобы использовать size для этого массива?

Comment: Такой функции нет и быть не может. Вместо простого массива используйте vector.

Comment: Если уж совсем правильно говорить - то компилятор не обязан хранить информацию о размерах массива. Другое дело, что компилятор должен вставлять для вызова free правильный код, поэтому какую-то информацию все таки он хранит. Но это очень сильно зависит от компилятора и платформы (да и от ключей оптимизации). К тому же, памяти под массивы может выделятся немножечко больше, что бы сделать доступ к памяти эффективнее.
Слышал байку, что в некоторых компиляторах специально массивы (даже в продакшн коде) делались на 1 больше - это сильно уменьшало глюки, когда ошибаются в индексе и пишут за пределы.

Comment: @KoVadim, в glibc  информация о динамически выделенной памяти хранится в самой выделенной памяти (см. Kerrisk "The Linux programming interface"). Даже для выделенной в стеке памяти в С++ размер может определяться динамически во время выполнения, поэтому компилятор не может этого знать, только в случае статического определения размера константным значением.

Comment: Поэтому я и написал, что это сильно зависит от *компилятора* и *платформы*.

Comment: А в чем, собственно, заключается сам вопрос? Что значит "использовать size"?

Answer (score 1):

В некоторых случаях, размер массива можно узнать, начните с чтения этой [статьи](http://demin.ws/blog/russian/2011/05/24/safe-sizeof-for-arrays-in-cpp/). Но правильный ответ - хранить самостоятельно. Либо использовать stl/boost.

Answer (score 1):

Маленький эксперимент показал:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int l = av[1]? atoi(av[1]): 10;
  int a[l];

  printf ("%d\n",sizeof(a));
}
```

-

> `c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc tsz.c 
> c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
> 40
> c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a 100
> 400
> c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $`

что sizeof() работает и для локальной динамики.

Размер в элементах теперь сами определите?

Comment: @mikillskegg, ну разве размер `int a[l]` известен при компиляции? 

Неужели у gcc есть возможности Вольфа Мессинга?

Comment: Хочу покаяться: в С99 sizeof действительно можно применять к массивам с run-time размером.